# Python module 'os' has no attribute 'mknod'

Tags: python, python-3.x, module, operating-system, mknod

I want to create a new file in Python for that I am using `mknod` command, but getting error as:

```
os.mknod();
AttributeError: module 'os' has no attribute 'mknod'
```

I am using windows and attributes other than `'mknod'` are working.

Comment: To expand vaultahs comment: You might have an own file called `os.py` which shadows the built-in package.

Comment: Hmm - a guess - are you on Windows...?  As you're talking about `os` calls, The Operating System you're working on is essential information...

Comment: Why are you trying to create a filesystem node without specifying a name?

Comment: first: you must have `os.py` in your path that shadows builtin module; second: why you are using mknod for the file? use `open`; third mknod without parameters? and what is this semicolon at the end? ;)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`os` offers functionality that is closely related to the OS you're using. If most other attributes can be accessed from `os` (meaning you haven't got a `os.py` file in the current dir masking the standard module) an `AttributeError` will 99% signal an unsupported function on your Operating System.

This is what the case is with `os.mknod` on Windows. Creating named pipes in `Windows` has, as far as I can understand, [very different semantics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Named_pipe#In_Windows).

Either way, if you are trying to use `mknod` to create named pipes you'd probably be better using [`mkfifo()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.mkfifo) (again, only `Unix` supported) . If you're using it to create ordinary files, don't, use `open()` which is portable.